# Using theme regions from .tpl.php file

Tags: 6, theming

I have defined many regions in my theme template. I would like to have a home page that uses these regions ... how can i use them? 
I have made a home.tpl.php but i don't know how to assign code to regions ... is it possible to do it even outside the page.tpl.php?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a region you would normally then do the following in your **page.tpl.php** file...

```
<?php if ($YOUR_REGION): ?>
    <?php print $YOUR_REGION; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You should have some similar examples setup already especially if you are using a theme that ships with Drupal.

You can create specific page templates...

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'my_page') {
    $variables['template_file'] = 'page-my_page';
  }
}
```

**Template suggestions**

See: http://drupal.org/node/1089642

**Context module**

Also, the Context module is brilliant for this sort of thing if you intend on having different regions for different pages you can use Context layout.

http://drupal.org/project/context